# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Exception when creating Application Context in Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception, applicationcontext

I am practicing with Spring, and am getting a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError exception when I try to instantiate the context. The Exception appears below, with my code following it. I have simplified my experiment from before.

The Exception

```
Oct 17, 2012 5:54:22 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@570c16b7: startup date [Wed Oct 17 17:54:22 CDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at helloworld.HelloWorldTest.main(HelloWorldTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:105)
... 7 more
```

My configuration XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="messageContainer" class="helloworld.MessageContainer">
    <property name="message" value="Hello World">
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageOutputService" class="helloworld.MessageOutputService">
</bean>
```

My test class.

```
package helloworld;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class HelloWorldTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("HelloWorldTest-context.xml");

    MessageContainer message = context.getBean(MessageContainer.class);

    MessageOutputService service = context.getBean(MessageOutputService.class);

    service.outputMessageToConsole(message);

}

}
```

Comment: are you positive you are using the same version for all the Spring JARs on the classpath?

Comment: Edit your post and include the _entire_ stacktrace.

Comment: @mattb I am using the lastest Springs jars as released on the Spring springspurce.org website.

Comment: @JimGarrison How would I go about getting the rest of the stack trace out of Eclipse/STS. This is what was shown in the console.

Comment: @cyotee are you using Maven? if so, can you post your POM?

Comment: @mattb Not using Maven is this experimentation.

Comment: Are you sure that's all the stack trace in the console?  The line "... 7 more" usually means this is particular stack is part of a larger stack dump and the "... 7 more" lines duplicate a previously displayed trace.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, I am sure that is all that was shown in the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line 17 does not correspond to the `context.getBean("userRepository"` line, it corresponds to the line before that where you initialize the Spring context. And actually you can also see that through stacktrace, it says it failed on Line 83 of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` where exists the constructor of that class.

Anyway, this exception is generally thrown when Spring can not create any bean for whatever reason (Exceptions in constructors, [resource loading issues](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?46346-Exception-after-deploying-java-lang-ExceptionInInitializerError), [class loading issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2272354/644766), etc.). I would suggest decreasing the log level for spring classes and for your own libraries to see what's going on underneath.

```
org.springframework=TRACE
com.gamemanagertest=TRACE
com.gamemanagertest=TRACE
```

And also check your resource files whether they're accessible by your application and constructors of all your objects if they produce any errors, etc.

Comment: I assume you have a logging framework installed, configure it with the levels given in the answer to see what breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I removed all the spring jars from the project.
Then again pasted all of them in a project folder & added all of them to build path.
And it worked.
Not very sure of how it happened..