# Loading ClassPathXmlApplicationContext within Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have the following line of code to load the application context:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring/spring-context.xml");
```

Initially, my project was a standalone maven project, and this worked fine.
I have now split up the project into two modules, both sharing a parent pom.xml.
All my testing so far has been from within Eclipse

The parent pom:

```
<groupId>parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
  <module>./config</module>
  <module>./ds</module>
</modules>
```

Header of the child project poms:

```
<parent>
   <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
   <groupId>parent</groupId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ds</groupId>
<artifactId>ds</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>ds</name>
```

In the parent directory there is just the pom.xml of the parent, and the two child projects are beneath this.
The maven command line build for the parent pom works fine.

Now, when the application context is loaded (again, running from Eclipse), the following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at      org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.createBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:195)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:128)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:527)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:441)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.bc.pog.ds.app.Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.<clinit>(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:109)
... 7 more
```

There is no clash of Spring jars within the projects.
Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks very much

Comment: Are you setting the same maven coordinates for the child pom's ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'maven coordinates'

Comment: Does Eclipse know these new projects exist? If you have moved the config files to another project then Eclipse needs to be told. Are there Eclipse errors in your workspace?

Comment: Maven Coordinates (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) are the unique identifiers of a dependency. When you split a maven project into 2 child projects and a parent project, each of the child projects should have different artifact id's, so make them unique. In your case I think they are the same and Spring is not able to load the correct jar.

Comment: Thanks Dhanush, but the second child pom is different

Comment: I see that another post last year talks about the same ssue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272354/why-do-i-get-a-nullpointerexception-when-initializing-spring
One of the final comments say it was resolved by "not making spring a system user library".
Not sure what that means, or whether it is relevant to what I am doing with Maven.